# using a database value to change css from code behind

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have been absolutely stumped on this for a couple of days now. Its getting to the point where I am unable to think about it rationally any more. Any guidance and wisdom any of you are willing to impart will be very  much appreciated.
My problem is that I have created a gridview, which loads from the database for each row a font name (its designation given by the font designers) and another column called FontFamily (which I need for the css). I can load the values from the db into the gridview easily enough but I am un able to use the 'FontFamily' value as my fontfamily css value. I have searched the internet and have not been able to come up with anything useful so far.
I have tried changing the font through code behind but am unable to use databound value as css property value.
The over all goal of the page is to show user which custom fonts are available. The font-family of lblFontExample should reflect the font listed in that row. Apologies if any of this sounds silly at all. I have been pulling my hair out over this for a few days now over this and logic seems to be in rapid decline so I thought it would be about time to ask for some help so thankyou in advanced to anyone who does help.

My code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

public partial class Admin_addFont : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private string fontUploadDirectory;
private string cssUploadDirectory;
private string connectionString =
  WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bncConn"].ConnectionString;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ensure files are uploaded to the right folder
    fontUploadDirectory = Path.Combine(
        Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "fonts");

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();

    }

}

protected void BindGrid()
{

    // define ado.net objects
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ProductDetails.bnc_Fonts", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    // define parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
    cmd.Parameters["@status"].Value = "Display";

    // attempt to connect to db, read data, fill dataset and bind gridview. Catch exceptions and close the connection.
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Fonts");
        grdFonts.DataSource = ds;    
        grdFonts.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lblFontGrd.Text = err.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}

protected void grdFonts_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

    grdFonts.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    BindGrid();

}}
```

My markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/AdminMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="addFont.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_addFont" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="RightCol" runat="Server">
        <h1>Fonts</h1>
        <div>
        <h2>Currently available fonts</h2>
    <asp:Label ID="lblFontGrd" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:GridView ID="grdFonts" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
         OnPageIndexChanging="grdFonts_PageIndexChanging">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775"></AlternatingRowStyle>

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="ID" FooterText="ID" HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="fontId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FontId") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Font Name" FooterText="Font Name" HeaderText="Font Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblfontName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FontName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblfontNameEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FontName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Example" FooterText="Example" HeaderText="Example">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label id="lblfontExample" runat="server" Text="This is an example"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="txtFontEx" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("FontFamily") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Discontinued?" HeaderText="Discontinued?" FooterText="Discontinued?">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Discontinued" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Discontinued") %>' Enabled="false" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Discontinued" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Discontinued") %>' Enabled="true" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />
                    </span>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999"></EditRowStyle>

        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></FooterStyle>

        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>

        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White"></PagerStyle>

        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333"></RowStyle>

        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333"></SelectedRowStyle>

        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>

        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>

        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8"></SortedDescendingCellStyle>

        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="flupCss" runat="server" />&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="lblCss" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="flupCss" Text="Upload file with file ending: .css"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="flupEot" runat="server" />&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="lblEot" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="flupEot" Text="Upload file with file ending: .eot"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="flupTtf" runat="server" />&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="lblTtf" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="flupTtf" Text="Upload file with file ending: .ttf"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="flupSvg" runat="server" />&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="lblSvg" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="flupEot" Text="Upload file with file ending: .eot"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="flupWoff" runat="server" />&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="lblWoff" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="flupWoff" Text="Upload file with file ending: .woff"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="flupWoff2" runat="server" />&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="lblWoff2" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="flupEot" Text="Upload file with file ending: .woff2"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnUploadFont" runat="server" Text="Add Font" />
</div>
```

And finally my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ProductDetails].[bnc_Fonts] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Status varchar(50) = '', 
@FontId tinyint = '',
@FontName varchar(50) = '',
@FontFamily varchar(50) = '',
@Discontinued bit = ''
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

if (@Status = 'Display')
begin
select FontId, FontName, FontFamily, Discontinued 
from ProductDetails.Fonts 
where Discontinued = 0
order by FontName asc   
end
if (@Status = 'FontFam')
begin
select FontFamily from ProductDetails.Fonts
where FontId = @FontId
end
if (@Status = 'Add')
begin
insert into ProductDetails.Fonts (FontName, FontFamily, Discontinued)
values (@FontName, @FontFamily, @Discontinued)
end
if (@Status = 'Delete')
begin
UPDATE ProductDetails.Fonts
SET Discontinued = @Discontinued
where FontId = @FontId
end
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Label id="lblfontExample" Font-Names='<%# BuildFont(Eval("FontFamily").ToString()) %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FontName") %>'></asp:Label>
```

In code behind :

```
public static string[] BuildFont(string font)
{
    string[] array = new string[1];
    array[0] = font;
    return array;
}
```

Font-Names example: Verdana, Times New Roman..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it but get the following error   An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in App_Web_s0oue43p.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.String[]'.